# Query to analyze two tables in two different databases and return where a column value does not exist in one of the tables

Tags: sql-server

SQL server 2016 on Azure:

Database1.Table1 contains 3 million records made up of multiple rows of any particular SourceId (e.g. 10 records for SourceId 1, 20 records for SourceId 2, 15 records for SourceId 3, etc).

Database2.Table1 is the information table about each of those SourceId's mentioned above. It contains 2k records, one for each existing SourceId, and the information about that source.

Both databases are on the same SQL Server instance.

What I need to construct is a query where it will look at all records of Database1.Table1, and return any records where the SourceId **does not exist** in Database2.Table1.

I've only ever done a JOIN on tables within a database, never on two different databases (although I believe it is a similar approach?)  Here is what I was able to come up with through research, which is not working (query returns no results in when it absolutely should):

```
SELECT DataSourceID, OrderNo
FROM Database1.Table1
JOIN Database2.Table1.SourceID = Database1.Table1.DataSourceID
WHERE NOT EXISTS Database2.Table1.SourceID
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: for simplicity's sake, I originally kept the name of the field the same for the 2 databases, when in actuality the names are different. Database1's field name is DataSourceId and Database2's field name is SourceId.  I see that I had to update this based on the answer posted by Sean_Lange.

EDIT #2: As mentioned above, this SQL Server is on Azure.  When testing the answers below in Production environment, I get an error that "reference to database and/or server name in Database1 is not supported in this version of SQL Server."  I have seen this before.  Azure SQL Server doesn't let you specify database names in queries.  I have no idea how I'm supposed to work around this then to do cross-database queries, but I will research Stack Overflow questions now to get past this first hurdle before continuing on the original issue.

EDIT #3: thanks to Sean Lange for posting the link to cross-database queries on Azure.  Checking that now, then will return to the original issue.

Comment: What exactly is "not working"?

Comment: You have 2 different dabases on the same instance or 2 different databases on different instances?

Comment: @Abhishek the query returns no results, but I have proven out that at least one sourceid does not exist in Database2 which is in Database1, so the returning of no results can not be correct.  I have updated my post to this effect.  Thanks.

Comment: @EzLo 2 different databases on the same instance.  I have updated my post to this effect to clarify.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NOT EXISTS but a simpler approach would be to use EXCEPT. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

```
SELECT SourceID, OrderNo
FROM Database1.Table1

EXCEPT

SELECT SourceID, OrderNo
FROM Database2.Table1
```

Comment: Hi Sean, I have just edited and updated my post.  The fields are actually NOT both called sourceid.  In my original post I did this to try and keep the post as simple as possible.  But I can see from your query that I should have been more explicit.  The field in Database1 is actually called DataSourceId.  Would your query still work now that the field names are not identical?  I am going to try and see in any case.

Comment: Sean, I'm getting an error that "Reference to database and/or server name in Database1 is not supported on this version of SQL Server."  I have seen this before with SQL Servers on Azure, but not sure how I'm supposed to run a cross-database query without being able to specify the database name???

Comment: Everything gets more "fun" with Azure. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/

Comment: Ok, got everything worked out and this EXCEPT is definitely the most efficient route to the data.  Marked as answer.  Thanks Sean!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SourceID, OrderNo
FROM Database1.Table1 AS T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1/0 FROM Database2.Table1 AS T2
                   WHERE T1.SourceID = T2.SourceID )
```

Comment: There is no need for a join here. You can use EXISTS directly.

Comment: The Select 1/0 is just for fun to get people wondering...  ;)

Comment: LOL I was curious why you chose that and assumed you know. ;)

Comment: LOL yeah when I first saw that I was amazed it doesn't throw an error...

Comment: I use that all the time to demonstrate that using select * is fine there.